# How to configure Eclipse project libraries to compile both on Windows and Linux?

Tags: java, linux, windows, eclipse, cross-platform

It's a simple OpenGL app. The problem is, JOGL needs native libraries, and I need to set "Native library location", which is different for Windows and Linux. Is it possible to share project settings between platforms?

I want to make the workspace setup process as simple as "checkout from SVN, compile, run".

Comment: Will you be willing to repackage things?

Comment: You mean, include libraries within the project?

Comment: Have you tried putting the native libraries for all the supported OSes in the same folder? That's usually what I do for my JOGL projects and it's worked well so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just Windows and Linux, you can put them in the same folder, as j flemm states.

The reason it works is because of the definition of [`System.loadLibrary()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.String)) in Java:

> **loadLibrary**
>
> public static void loadLibrary(String
>   libname)
>
> Loads the system library
>   specified by the libname argument. The
>   manner in which a library name is
>   mapped to the actual system library is
>   system dependent.

That means `System.loadLibrary("jogl")` will try to load `jogl.dll` on Windows and `libjogl.so` on Linux.  It's pretty nice.