# Java Project with native libraries for different platforms

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java project that uses [JOGL](http://jogamp.org/jogl/www/) and therefore needs to include different native libraries for different platforms. Now I want to set up the eclipse project to automatically chose the correct libraries. In the `.classpath` file you can specify *one* native location:

```
<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/jogl/jar/jogl.all.jar">
    <attributes>
        <attribute name="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.CLASSPATH_ATTR_LIBRARY_PATH_ENTRY" value="de.yogularm.desktop/lib/jogl/windows-amd64"/>
    </attributes>
</classpathentry>
```

If multiply classpathentries specify a native location, Eclipse also tries to load the libraries for other platforms and fails.

How can I make eclipse chose the directory? I want to share the project and make setup for further developers as easy as possible.

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618425/how-to-configure-eclipse-project-to-compile-both-on-windows-and-linux?

Comment: Would be a good alternative, but it lacks support for both 64 and 32 bit systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create several .classpath files (.classpath_Windows, .classpath_Linux etc.) and then create symbolic link to required version (Win/Lin/Mac) named ".classpath" 
The problem will appear whan you want to change any entry inside any .classpath_XXXXXXX - then you will have to update other .classpath files.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse lacks the feature you want. So, you can do it from Java.

Instead of calling `System.loadLibrary`, call `System.load`. This requires you to write code to calculate the correct pathname based on the current platform. You'll need to use -D to pass a value in to say what the current platform is, or read it from a file.

This removes `java.library.path` from the equation.

If your JNI library has dependencies, you will also need to set PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, or DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH. Unless you take the further step of looking at https://github.com/bimargulies/jni-origin-testbed. For Windows, however, the necessary machinations with the delay-loader aren't in there.

Comment: Very interesting answer, I'll try this soon.

Comment: As I see, I would have to change the code of the referenced library, and this isn't practicable. But your answer would be perfect if I wrote the library on my own.

Comment: Why would you have to change the code of the referenced library? I didn't when I did this.

Comment: The library *gluegen* tries to call loadLibrary() when the class is initialized, even if I load the native library before a call to the class.

Comment: Oh, yes, that would be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

I may be wrong, but I think the native libraries are things like DLLs, shared objects, etc., and don't go on the classpath at all. Each environment will have something like a PATH variable or the like, which will need to include the native libraries. The user may have to some configuration (either within Eclipse, or via environment variables).

Comment: The native paths are not inclued in the *classpath*, they are just declared in the classpath file. Eclipse uses them for the PATH variable when debugging. Only using one platform, this is no problem and surely the intended way.

Comment: Good point - I obviously didn't read the question carefully enough.

Answer (score -1):

Libraries are not searched within the classpath, the system PATH and the property `java.library.path`.

In your case may be a custom [ClassLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html) implementation, especially the `findLibrary(..)` and `loadLibrary(..)` methods. This would allow to select an appropriate library based on the detected OS.